# Which is faster to delete - stack or vector?

Tags: c++, stl

I am currently creating a program and I have to remember a series of strings which in most cases will have to be deleted right after they are remembered - and speed will be important. So my question is, which one of the two is faster to delete/deallocate or if there is something ever faster or something that will suit my needs even more, what is it ?

Thank you very much

Comment: If it matters, you benchmark it. If you don't benchmark it, then it must not really matter.

Comment: OK, I get your point

Comment: A stack can be backed by a vector (though it defaults to a deque).  If that configuration is used, then the delete time should be equivalent.  But I'd guess that a stack backed by a deque probably wouldn't be significantly slower.  You'll probably get a lot of comments saying that you simply need to measure for yourself.

Comment: Also, delete times are almost completely irrelevant in release builds. Don't worry about delete time.

Comment: If you can avoid allocations (deallocations are more expensive than allocations) do that! This implies the internal memory management of structures (strings),

Comment: If you are just going to keep allocating and deleting then why not just keep them around and reset them? That would be *much* faster than deleting/creating.

Comment: I have found that deque has got clear() function, so I will stick to that and hope it will do the job, thanks for comments

Comment: @Jesse_Pinkman, no you shouldn't - if speed is critical just measure the alternatives and select the fastest. Don't assume/imagine things, speed also depends on a series of architecture/impementation/compiler/optimisation-dependent subtleties you won't be aware of. Measure, it'll only take you 5-10 lines of code and a few minutes to know for sure..

Comment: Assuming that you have true stack access (LIFO), the fastest solution is a custom LIFO allocator.